# rsync: Protect non-empty directories on receiver

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to `rsync` my project folders to a server, and that includes various source code etc.

```
rsync "$GOPATH/src/" -rm \
    -f '+ */' \
    -f '+ *.go' \
    -f '+ *.s' \
    -f '+ *.html' \
    -f '+ *.js' \
    -f '+ *.css' \
    -f '+ fonts/*' \
    -f 'P */' \
    -f '- *' \
    myserver:its/gopath/src/
```

I want to remove superfluous code, and avoid creating directories on the receiver where possible. However by providing the `-m`, `--prune-empty-directories` option, I get warnings that the directories are not empty on the receiver.

```
*deleting github.com/anacrolix/jitter/.git/hooks/
cannot delete non-empty directory: github.com/anacrolix/jitter/.git
cannot delete non-empty directory: bitbucket.org/anacrolix/go-utils/bin
*deleting bitbucket.org/anacrolix/go-utils/bin/
```

How can I avoid attempting to delete those directories, or squash that warning via an rsync flag?

Comment: using a `--exclude '.git'` tag?

Comment: @armnotstrong: That's helpful because it reduces the number of warnings, but there are still other directories that I want protected.

Comment: I am not very experienced with rsync, but according to the manual using `--include` and `--exclude` should be fairly enough **--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN** and **--include=PATTERN  don't exclude files matching PATTERN** According to this snippet, should write a  exclude pattern and re-include them if it matches anything that you really don't want to exclude.

Comment: @armnotstrong: It's necessary to include directories so that files are checked inside them. The prune to remove those unnecessarily added however seems to apply to the receiver side as well.

Comment: Could you update your answer with an example of directory structure and mark what you wish to delete and to leave?

Comment: Why don't you use `--exclude-from=FILE|PATTERN` or `--include-from=FILE|PATTERN`. That `FILE` will be an input for your patterns actually (how may you need/want, each on a separate line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to combine `-m`, and `-f 'P */'` *before* `-f '+ */'`. This protects directories from being deleted on the receiver-side, and doesn't create unnecessary ones to house the sent files.